# Neo4j - How can I improve query execution time (server consumption)?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I use a Neo4j database (access via docker) with 177,000,000 nodes and 352,000,000 relationships. This is a sample query I want to improve:

```
MATCH (a:NodeA {prop1: $prop1})<-[:BA]-(b:NodeB)-[:BC]->(c:NodeC)-[:CD]->(d:NodeD)-[:DE]->(e:NodeE)
RETURN e.prop2, a.prop1, a.prop3, c.prop4, c.prop5, b.prop6;
```

There is an index on prop1.

I used the python v1 driver to measure query execution times. There are two different times in the ResultSummary:

- The time it took the server to make the result available for consumption (I call it 'available' time)
- The time it took the server to consume the result (I call it 'consumption' time)

My queries have short 'available' times (1 to 80 ms) but very large 'consumption' times (up to 350000 ms).

I tried to optimize the queries by using parameters and I changed some memory configuration (increased page cache size and reduced heap size) and that leaded to shorter 'available' times (1 to 15 ms) and also shorter 'consumption' times (20000 to 250000 ms).
Unfortunately, the consumption time is still very high!

My questions:

- I do not understand well the difference between these two time measures. What do they measure?
- How can I improve my queries? (apart from indexes)

Thank you,
Reima

Comment: How many results do you have? (= what does `MATCH (.. your match clause.) RETURN COUNT(*)` return?)

Comment: There are about 9000 results.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question I guess the response is streamed so available time is when the first record arrives and consumption time is when the complete result set has been received and processed , somewhat time difference between last record received and first record received. My apologies if my assumption turn out to be wrong.
To answer your second question keep as much data in memory cache as possible or use SSD if high RAM is not an option.Following link may be of help.

1) [Linux file system tuning](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/performance/)

2) [Memory tuning](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/performance/#memory-tuning)

3) [Disk and ram considerations](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/performance/disks-ram-and-other-tips/)

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. Now, I better understand these terms.
I already changed the memory configurations and that improved query execution time, but it is still very slow.